# Implement hash-table in C++

Tags: c++, hash, hashmap, hashtable

The following is the implementation of hashtable using C++. Can you please help me to understand what `HashEntry **table` is? Why it is declared as a double pointer? Is it a array and each value of the array is `HashEntry`?

```
  class HashEntry {
    private:
          int key;
          int value;
    public:
          HashEntry(int key, int value) {
                this->key = key;
                this->value = value;
          }

          int getKey() {
                return key;
          }

          int getValue() {
                return value;
          }
    };

    const int TABLE_SIZE = 128;






    class HashMap {
    private:
          HashEntry **table;
    public:
          HashMap() {
                table = new HashEntry*[TABLE_SIZE];
                for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
                      table[i] = NULL;
          }

          int get(int key) {
                int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);
                while (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->getKey() != key)
                      hash = (hash + 1) % TABLE_SIZE;
                if (table[hash] == NULL)
                      return -1;
                else
                      return table[hash]->getValue();
          }

          void put(int key, int value) {
                int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);
                while (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->getKey() != key)
                      hash = (hash + 1) % TABLE_SIZE;
                if (table[hash] != NULL)
                      delete table[hash];
                table[hash] = new HashEntry(key, value);
          }     

          ~HashMap() {
                for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
                      if (table[i] != NULL)
                            delete table[i];
                delete[] table;
          }
    };
```

Comment: just for interview question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Don't you mean `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: @user2899162 Yes, `std::unordered_map` is the hash map implementation actually.

Comment: Yes, but the question is, I don't understand what `HashEntry **` means in the above code.

Comment: @Anni_housie HashEntry** is a dynamic 2D Array

Comment: @OmidCompSCI, is it TABLE_SIZE * TABLE_SIZE  in dimension?

Comment: @Anni_housie look at this link it is very useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this code, `table` is a pointer to a pointer to HashEntry

```
HashEntry **table;
```

The general rule is to start with the variable name and the basic type, go right as much as possible then go left, see this excellent description

http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html

So you start with the variable, `table`, and the basic type, `HashEntry` which is furthest to the left. Note that the article describes the rules for 'C' where a basic type can be a `struct`, think of your C++ class `HashEntry` as a 'C' struct.

`table is ... HashEntry`

There is nothing else to the right of `table` in the declaration, so go left, and you have "*" which stands for *pointer to*:

`table is pointer to ... HashEntry`

Again you must go left in the declaration and consume the next "*", you now have

`table is pointer to pointer to HashEntry`

... and you are done.

It is perhaps unfortunate that `table` was declared that way, because table implies array, and it is not declared as an array.  It turns out that in C++, as in C, an array "decays" into a pointer when it is passed to a function.  Here "decays" means you have lost information, namely the size of the array.

An equivalent declaration, which I think would give the reader more insight would be:

```
HashEntry * table[];
```

Using the rules about how to interpret variable declarations, this should be read as

`table is undimensioned array of pointer to HashEntry`

This is equivalent from the compiler's point of view to the previous declaration, because an *undimensioned array* is passed as a pointer to the type of the elements of the array (the value being the address of the first element, at offset 0).  A "dimensioned array" also decays to a pointer, with the loss of the dimension information.  See this SO answer for more information on decaying of arrays to pointers.

[What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying?noredirect=1&lq=1)